# php скрипт отправка писем через smtp

Tags: php, html, smtp

Здравствуйте коллеги.
Проблема заключается в неработающем скрипте по отправке из форм обратной связи на сайте, домен которого закреплён на masterhost.ru
Как мне написали решить проблему:
У вас не прописана авторизованная отправка из скриптов сайта. Инструкция есть на нашем сайте:

- https://masterhost.ru/support/doc/windows/smtp-auth/
  Тут написано:

  **Поскольку отправка анонимных сообщений с серверов виртуального Windows-хостинга запрещена, отправку писем следует производить через SMTP-сервер, для чего так же возможно использовать и нашу почтовую систему.**

Как это понимать, толком не знаю.

Хочу отметить что мой скрипт работает на двух других хостингах, а тут нет, ну вот хоть убей. А домен куплен здесь.

И дан пример скрипта на php. Но вот что там менять, какие переменные изменить, как связать это с html-формой я вообще не понимаю, первый раз сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой. Не знаю как правильно вставить php код сюда, поэтому очень прошу, умоляю посмотреть его здесь если не трудно:

https://masterhost.ru/support/doc/windows/smtp-auth/

Это будет неоценимая помощь.

Comment: Подставить ваш логин и пароль.

Comment: Не мучайся, вот готовый рабочий скрипт - https://blog.212d.ru/blog/otpravka-pochty-cherez-smtp-s-pomoshchyu-php